# Read image from SQL Server to path

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to read image from a SQL Server `VARBINARY(MAX)` column to output folder without using any 3 rd party software?

Just using T-SQL and query

Comment: not clear what are you asking

Comment: @Ravi There are plenty of images saved as binary to my sql table. I want to read those images as jpg and store to folder on desktop

Comment: might be useful https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80817/how-to-export-an-image-column-to-files-in-sql-server

Comment: The short answer is No. The link suggested by Ravi is an option using BCP or this link for powershell is another option https://niallbest.com/script-to-export-sql-server-blob-data-with-ado-net-via-powershell/